# Using Data provider in the second @test method in the same class file is not running successfully

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

In my requirement, I have "Add" button in the screen comes in "ClassC". It opens the popup module. where I can add more numbers of values and save.

My code runs with one `@Test` method with data provider iteration. But it failed after one iteration. So, I created one additional `@test` method with data provider.

Code getting failed after the successful run of first `@test` method. Not finding the first element comes under the second `@test` method.

> ```
> Failed: columns("Encounter", "account", "Encounter")
> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException Expected condition failed:
> waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:
> //*[@id='txtDisplayName'] (tried for 4 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval).
> ```

```
public class classc extends classb {
    
    @Test
    public void Create()
    {
    // Redirection to the screen
        obj1.actiononMenu(driver, wait, "//abbr[@class='ti-settings']", "//samp[text() = 'Focus']", "//li[2]/ul/li[1]/a");

    long focusauditTimetaken = (long) obj1.javatimeout(driver);
        this.wait = obj1.explicitWait(driver, (int) focusauditTimetaken);

        // Clicking add button
        WebElement addButton = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//div[2]/button");
        obj1.clickElement(addButton);
    
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "addingColumns")
    public void columns(String displayName, String columnName, String uniqueName)
    {
        // Passing first value from the DataProvider (displayName)  
        WebElement displayColumn = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//*[@id='txtDisplayName']");
        obj1.clickElement(displayColumn);
        obj1.sendtext(displayColumn, displayName);
        
    // Passing second value from the DataProvider (columnName)  
        WebElement columnDropdown = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//div[contains(text(), 'Select Column Name')]");
        obj1.clickElement(columnDropdown);
        
        obj1.dropdownfilter(driver, wait, "//div[@class='filter']/input", columnName);
        
    // Passing thrid value from the Data Provider (uniqueName)
        WebElement uniqueDropdown = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//div[contains(text(), 'Select Column')]");
        obj1.clickElement(uniqueDropdown);
        
        obj1.dropdownfilter(driver, wait, "//div[@class='filter']/input", uniqueName);
        
    // Save first set values 
        WebElement addcolumnButton = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//button[@class='button create hvr-glow hvr-icon']");
        obj1.clickElement(addcolumnButton);
        
        
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name = "addingColumns")
    public Object[][] addColumns()
    {
        return new Object[][]
                {
            {"AA","BB","CC"},
            {"11","22","33"}
                };
    }
            
}
```

The class c extends the class B.

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

@Test
public void project() {
    
    try {
        obj1.implicitWait(driver, 10);          
        WebElement groupName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='placeholder']"))));
        groupName.click();
        
        WebElement inputText = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='filter']//input"))));
        inputText.click();
        inputText.sendKeys("Par");
        inputText.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
        inputText.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        
        long timetaken = (long) obj1.javatimeout(driver);
        this.wait = obj1.explicitWait(driver, (int) timetaken); 
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Project group not selected " +e);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    
}
```

The class B extends the class A.

```
public class ClassA{
    
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    
    Commonclass obj1 = new Commonclass();
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void callbrowser()
    {
        this.driver = obj1.selectBrowser(driver, "Chrome");
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        driver.get("https://Link Goes here");
        
        long timetaken = (long) obj1.javatimeout(driver);
        wait = obj1.explicitWait(driver, (int) timetaken);
        
        WebElement signin = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//*[@id='txtSigninID']");
        obj1.sendtext(signin, "My Name");
            
        WebElement password = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//*[@id='txtPassword']");
        obj1.sendtext(password, "my password");
        
        WebElement submit = obj1.selectElement(wait, "//*[@name='btnSignIn']");
        obj1.clickElement(submit);
    }
    
    
}
```

The entire code runs if am having single @test method. Why two @test method in a single class is not working. I am adding the testng.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
<classes>
<class name="com.abc.def.aaa.classa"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: I see You extend some other class, do You have during webDriver instantiation some timeout set, probably this is causing issue, because element cannot be found. My suggestion is that You put all your elements into PageObject design, it will resolve lot of issues that You have. Here is great link to start of https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html.

Comment: Provide more info HTML, driver instantiation etc.

Comment: Hi. Kovacic. I have added additional information. Please check. My problem is the entire code runs when there is one @test method.

Comment: @MukunthRajendran - How do you expect anyone to basically run the code you shared and find out what is wrong, because it has a lot of dependencies on other classes, which you have not shared. Please edit your question and kindly add all the contextual information that is required

Comment: @Krishnan - Sorry, I have provided enough information needed.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - If my code not helps you decode that's fine. But I guess i can expect the answer for this question. Why would a test failed after adding additional test method. My code runs successfully with one test method.

Comment: @MukunthRajendran - If anyone has to try and figure out why you are experiencing failures, you would need to provide with a sample that can be used to run and simulate the problem. With what you have shared that is not possible. Please refer [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines. And yes you can expect an answer, no second thoughts on that. Please put yourself in the shoes of others and check, if you were to be posed with such a question,would you be able to debug ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan But how you will run this code because I am working in the intranet web page. which you can access.

Comment: @Mukunth precisely point. How do you envision anyone to be able to figure out the root cause without running the code ? There is nothing that stands obvious from the code that you shared. That is why I was asking for more information.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan. Okie. You cannot run my code. I have provided all information you asked for. Nothing left. I removed the sensitive data in my code and published here.

Comment: @MukunthRajendran, from code that You've sent and exception that You've get, i see that You have implicit wait 10s. Maybe this is causing the problem, because the element You've been searching have not yet been found by driver? 
POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
1. increase implicit timeout to lets say 30s
2. put elements into PageObjects, 
3.Try removing <test thread-count="5" name="Test"> if You are not running in concurrent runs,